# handsontable - Simulating "pressing enter" in on all cells after load

Tags: javascript, handsontable

Let me try to explain.

I have programmed some JavaScript into the **afterChange: function** that takes the value of Column 2, looks up a database, and puts a different value into Column 3.

This works great when you're entering in the information from scratch on a new handsontable, but I want to **load data**, and when I do that, I need to go to each cell and press enter to make my JavaScript from **afterChange: function** work.

Is there a way to simulate pressing enter on all cells after handsontable fully loads?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to simulate the enter on all the cells, you can trigger the afterChange event on all the cells?

Example: Handsontable.hooks.run(instance, 'afterChange',.......);

This should invoke your registered handler for afterChange where you can update the dependent cells.